# Анимировать логотип при наведении на разные пункты меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Не понимаю как сделать анимацию раскатывающегося ковра для меню.
Есть вот такое меню с логотипом в SVG:
[image: меню сейчас выглядит так:]

Мне бы хотелось при наведении на любой из пунктов меню, чтобы происходила анимация разворота ковра до этого пункта:[image: вот так]

Ну и если последний пункт меню, то полностью раскрыть ковер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Интересует именно как организовать плавный переход и сам разворот ковра от пункта к пункту?

Comment: аххахах ковер разворачивается))0

Comment: Тут не ткацкая фабрика. Ковер с пунктами меню должен быть предоставлен в минимально воспроизводимом коде.

Comment: А вообще, можно просто длинную пикчу сделать Начало ковра, потом линию 500пх влево рулон + линию белую вправо, и двигать саму пикчу через трансформ

Comment: это делается не сложно: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvdxyab - вот пример